# MySQL - group by but with different date range

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with the following query.

I have the following table with information,

| Id | temperature | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 2000-10-01 05:00:00 |
| 2 | 10 | 2000-10-01 05:10:00 |
| 5 | 12 | 2000-10-01 05:20:00 |
| 22 | 12 | 2000-10-01 05:30:00 |
| 35 | 13 | 2000-10-01 05:40:00 |
| 45 | 13 | 2000-10-01 05:50:00 |
| 60 | 10 | 2000-10-01 06:00:00 |
| 89 | 10 | 2000-10-01 06:10:00 |

I tried the following query but I don't get the expected result,

```
SELECT
    MIN(date) as min_date,
    MAX(date) as max_date,
    COUNT(*) as count,
    temperature
FROM
  temperatures
GROUP BY
   temperature
ORDER BY
   id;
```

Obtained result

| min_date | max_date | count | temperature |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000-10-01 05:00:00 | 2000-10-01 06:10:00 | 4 | 10 |
| 2000-10-01 05:20:00 | 2000-10-01 05:30:00 | 2 | 12 |
| 2000-10-01 05:40:00 | 2000-10-01 05:50:00 | 2 | 13 |

Expected result

| min_date | max_date | count | temperature |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000-10-01 05:00:00 | 2000-10-01 05:10:00 | 2 | 10 |
| 2000-10-01 05:20:00 | 2000-10-01 05:30:00 | 2 | 12 |
| 2000-10-01 05:40:00 | 2000-10-01 05:50:00 | 2 | 13 |
| 2000-10-01 06:00:00 | 2000-10-01 06:10:00 | 2 | 10 |

I appreciate the help you can give me if someone has more clear how I could get the expected result.

Greetings,

**EDIT**

First of all, apologies for the delay in responding and many thanks to everyone who took the time to respond and provide suggestions.

I put them a little more in context, the data that is being consulted are temperature records, but this temperature can be maintained for an indefinite period of time (so there are records with the same temperature but with different date and time) and in any moment can change.

The final result is to show this data in a chart, for example in a line chart.

The detail is that if the query returns all the data, the graph would be drawn with many equal temperatures in certain time ranges as shown in the following example.

**"I am aware that a solution is to store only one record for each change in temperature, but that is no longer up to me."**

[image]

The ultimate goal is to show the changing temperatures.

[image]

Therefore, I thought of grouping the data by temperature, what happens is that by grouping in this way I do not achieve the final objective since situations like this can occur.

**DATA TABLE**

| Id | temperature | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 2000-10-01 05:00:00 |
| 2 | 10 | 2000-10-01 05:10:00 |
| 5 | 12 | 2000-10-01 05:20:00 |
| 22 | 12 | 2000-10-01 05:30:00 |
| 35 | 13 | 2000-10-01 05:40:00 |
| 45 | 13 | 2000-10-01 05:50:00 |
| 60 | 10 | 2000-10-01 06:00:00 |
| 89 | 10 | 2000-10-01 06:10:00 |

**Obtained result**

| min_date | max_date | count | temperature |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ***2000-10-01 05:00:00*** | ***2000-10-01 06:10:00*** | 4 | 10 |
| 2000-10-01 05:20:00 | 2000-10-01 05:30:00 | 2 | 12 |
| 2000-10-01 05:40:00 | 2000-10-01 05:50:00 | 2 | 13 |

**Expected result**

| min_date | max_date | count | temperature |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ***2000-10-01 05:00:00*** | ***2000-10-01 05:10:00*** | 2 | 10 |
| 2000-10-01 05:20:00 | 2000-10-01 05:30:00 | 2 | 12 |
| 2000-10-01 05:40:00 | 2000-10-01 05:50:00 | 2 | 13 |
| ***2000-10-01 06:00:00*** | ***2000-10-01 06:10:00*** | 2 | 10 |

Again, thank you very much to everyone.

Greetings,

Comment: What is your exception exactly? It's clear you are not going to group by temperture . Because in your excepted data there are two rows with same temperature. How do you want to group data? What does different data range mean? I hope to help you

Comment: What does the id represent?

Answer (score 1):

I started a new group every time there's a temp change.

```
select    min(date)        as min_date
         ,max(date)        as max_date
         ,count(*)         as count
         ,max(temperature) as temperature
from     (
          select *
         ,row_number() over(order by Id) - row_number() over(partition by temperature order by Id) as tmp_chng
          from   t 
          ) t
group by tmp_chng, temperature
order by min_date
```

| min_date | max_date | count | temperature |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000-10-01 05:00:00 | 2000-10-01 05:10:00 | 2 | 10.0000 |
| 2000-10-01 05:20:00 | 2000-10-01 05:30:00 | 2 | 12.0000 |
| 2000-10-01 05:40:00 | 2000-10-01 05:50:00 | 2 | 13.0000 |
| 2000-10-01 06:00:00 | 2000-10-01 06:10:00 | 2 | 10.0000 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6b6666c02686bee65de45cffb98de862&hide=1)

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score -1):

Without further elaboration on your expected output, I can only assume based on the output provided, you intend to group by temperature first,then by year_month_day_hour. If so,try this:

```
SELECT
    MIN(date) as min_date,
    MAX(date) as max_date,
    COUNT(*) as count,
    temperature
FROM
  temperatures
GROUP BY
   temperature,date_format(date,'%y%m%d%H')
ORDER BY
    date_format(date,'%y%m%d%H');

-- result set:
# min_date, max_date, count, temperature
2000-10-01 05:20:00, 2000-10-01 05:30:00, 2, 12
2000-10-01 05:00:00, 2000-10-01 05:10:00, 2, 10
2000-10-01 05:40:00, 2000-10-01 05:50:00, 2, 13
2000-10-01 06:00:00, 2000-10-01 06:10:00, 2, 10
```

Comment: This's only based on assumptions, just like you presume there are always pairs. Without further clarification from the OP, I (we) can only perceive things from individual's point of view. The OP has neither illustrated the scenario nor explained his intended output, so we can either choose to try to be helpful, or just leave it be.